# Is there anyway to override the onMouseLeave event when using the dojo tooltipdialogue?

Tags: dojo

The code below is from the standard example from the dojo tooltipdialogue.
I have a requirement to stop the behaviour of the tooltip closing when you move the mouse away from the dialogue. Is there a way to override the onMouseLeave event to keep the tooltip open until the user clicks a button with in the tooltipdialogue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../_static/js/dojo/../dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">

<script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
<script src='../_static/js/dojo/dojo.js'></script>

<script>
require([
"dijit/TooltipDialog",
"dijit/popup",
"dojo/on",
"dojo/dom",
"dojo/domReady!"
], function(TooltipDialog, popup, on, dom){
var myTooltipDialog = new TooltipDialog({
    id: 'myTooltipDialog',
    style: "width: 300px;",
    content: "<p>I have a mouse leave event handler that will close the    dialog.",
    onMouseLeave: function(){
        popup.close(myTooltipDialog);
    }
});

on(dom.byId('thenode'), 'mouseover', function(){
    popup.open({
        popup: myTooltipDialog,
        around: dom.byId('thenode')
    });
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
<div id="thenode">Move the mouse over me to pop up the dialog.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just remove the `onMouseLeave` event handler from the `myTooltipDialog` declaration. And close the popup on click of another button inside the `tooltipDialog` whichever you want to be handling the event.